# Bootstrap affix on navbar, property is always on (class always active)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I am trying to implement Bootstrap's affixed navbar, like in 
[this example.](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h)

Here is [a pen](https://codepen.io/ahermstad/pen/oBzGJw) of what I have. It seems that the 'affix' class is always activated on the navbar element. That is, when I do

```
.affix {
   top: 0;
}
```

The navbar automatically goes to the top on page load, when what I want it to do is be under the name and title. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

EDIT: Fixed the example link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRrBNK

I've just moved the title and sub text and added a class within

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" data-spy="affix" data-offset top="197">      
<div class="navbrand">
  <h1> John Smith</h1></div>
  <h4> Developer and Engineer </h4>
```

Comment: if you wanted the title to be removed on scroll, I recommend JQuery.

Comment: I was meaning something more along the lines of the behavior in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&stacked=h Notice how the navbar is sitting below the content, but then sticks to the top of the page when it scrolls past it. Basically I want the navbar to sit under the name and title, and then stick to the stop once it scrolls past.